# How to use joined columns on hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have 3 entities joined via onetoone relations. My goal is get entities using hibernate criteria where `match.status != null`. And how to tell hibernate to not join `algo` entity to result, should be (pick.algo = null).

```
@Entity
public class Pick {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int pid;

  @Column(columnDefinition="DATETIME")
  private Date insertTime;

  @Column(columnDefinition="DATETIME")
  private Date setupResTime;

  @OneToOne
  private DbMatch match;

  @OneToOne
  private Algo algo;

  @Transient
  private Integer algoID;
  ....
```

Criteria query:

```
public List<Pick> getPicksHistory(){
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Pick.class);  
    criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("match.status"));
    return criteria.list();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the hibernate documentation (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-associations) :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Pick.class);
criteria.createAlias("match", "m");
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("m.status"));
criteria.setFetchMode("algo", FetchMode.LAZY);
criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add alias and apply your condition to the alias name

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Pick.class);  
criteria.createAlias("match", "match", JoinType.INNER_JOIN); //<---
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("match.status"));
```

TO get nulls you can use e.g. JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN